# Executing my function before loading of kernel (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-service-container

Would like to build in a simple validation for the value of the *APP_ENV* parameter in my Laravel application. I want the parameter to be either *dev, tst, acc* or *prd*. If it's not one of these, my Laravel application should throw an exception and quit. Something like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Exception;

$envs = ['dev','tst','acc','prd'];
if(!in_array(App::environment(), $envs)) {
  throw new Exception('Invalid APP_ENV value.');
}
```

I would like this to be done early in the bootstrapping sequence. I suspect I should put it in a [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) and register that in */config/app.php*. But this particular thing is still a bit untransparent for me, with my limited experience.

Where should I put my code snippet above, so that it gets executed early in the bootstrapping process?

Comment: you can add it in AppServiceProvider boot method

Comment: @JohnLobo Your suggestion works perfectly. Maybe you could answer it as an actual answer?